# Max length em input type number html

Tags: jquery, html5, angularjs, input

Tenho um input type number

```
     <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label class="lb">Valor total</label> 
         <input  type="number"  min="0" id="idValorTotalProdutoP" ng-model="subTotalProduto"  class="form-control"/>                     
    </div>
```

e por ser um valor além de no banco de dados constar 15,4 preciso que este `input` 
fique com o maxlength de 15,4 
alguém sabe ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

o `maxlength` funciona por caracteres digitados (inputados), e não para o formato numerico especifico, o que você pode usar é o atributo `max=""` e vai ter que usar o `step` para adicionar de 0.01 em 0.01 (ou 0.1), assim:

```html
<input class="foo" type="number" min="0" max="15.4" maxlength="4" step="0.01">
```

> **Nota:** o `maxlength=` esta com o valor `4` e irá limitar para quatro digitos, no caso a intenção é algo como `00.00`

Mas é claro que se digitar manualmente será possível digitar um numero bem maior, então você pode usar os eventos [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/input_event) e [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event), exemplo:

```js
// Cria uma função que será usando no keyup e no blur
maxNumber(document.querySelector(".foo"));
maxNumber(document.querySelector(".bar"));

function maxNumber(input)
{
    input.addEventListener('input', handler);
    input.addEventListener('blur', handler);

    var running = false;

    function handler() {
        // Para evitar conflito entre o input e o blur
        if (running) return;
        
        // Bloqueia múltiplas chamadas do input e blur
        running = true;

        var max = parseFloat(this.getAttribute("max"));
        
        // Se o input for maior que max="" ele irá fixa o valor maximo no value
        if (parseFloat(this.value) > max) this.value = max;
        
        // Habilita novamente as chamadas do blur e keyup
        running = false;
    };
}
```

```html
<p>
  <strong>Max 15,4:</strong>
  <input class="foo" type="number" min="0" max="15.4" maxlength="4" step="0.01">
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Max 22,66:</strong>
  <input class="bar" type="number" min="0" max="22.66" maxlength="4" step="0.02">
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o step com o numero de casas decimais que deseja aceitar

Ficaria assim
 `<input type="number" step="0.1" min="0" max="15.4">`

Nesse caso o input vai de 0 até 15.4 avançando de um em um decimo.

ps: O uso do max e do min não impede o usuário de colocar um valor além dos limites manualmente.